# KnockoutJS select in column- data binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a problem with table, and select (in column).
I have a table, bound to 'grades' collection.
Grades consists of:

- student {indexNumber,name,surname}
- grade
- dateOfGrade

Now i have html table, which works fine:

```html
<table id='ocenyTable' data-bind='visible: Oceny().length > 0'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Numer indeksu studenta</th>
       <th>Ocena</th>
       <th>Data wystawienia</th>
       <th Akcje/>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody data-bind=" foreach: Oceny ">
     
       <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: studentObject.indexNumber, uniqueName: true' /></td>
       <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: grade, uniqueName: true' /></td>
       <td><input  class='required' data-bind='value: dateOfGrade, uniqueName: true' type="date" /></td>
       <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeOcena'>Usuń</a></td>
       <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.save'>Zapisz</a></td>
       
      </tr>
     </tbody>
```

But the problem is: instead of input

I would like to have select, like:

```html
<select data-bind="options: $root.students, optionsText: 'indexNumber', optionsValue: 'indexNumber', value: student.indexNumber" name="studentIndexNumber" required>
      </select>
```

Problem is, this select should contains list of all indexNumber's from student collection.
When i tried binding from js, using ko.applybinding, it says i cant bind multiple collections...
Mentioned select starts working, when i put him outside table (because, then  i can bind data to that select !).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not sure how the error is being output but what jumps out at me is the syntax in your data-bind is not correct. Your value parameter should be a variables like 'selectedStudent'.  So to calirfy the optionsValue and OptionsText is in relation to what you see and set in the dropdown but the value binding is the variable which gets set after you select an option. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Its all fine, i did it on purpose (it doesnt matter).What is more its working outside table, when i do ko.applybinding on that html element. Problem is that i cant apply two collections to the same html element (or its descedants). So how im supposed to get full list of indexNumbers ?
I though i could send it in body after GET call on grades,
but its against REST rules. (its a academic project- gosh).
I solved it by editing innerHTML, and added list manually- but then model doesnt change :). Thanks for your suggestion hdifen

Comment: so I'm a bit confused the select replaces the table? or the table remains and each input is replaced by a select? or the table remains and there is one select per row?

Comment: I know solution of my problem: all data (students, grades,subjects) should be in one viewmodel.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik it would be helpful to future visitors if you could add your solution below and mark the question as solved. Thanks!

Comment: The code remains unchanged. Everything is fine by html side.
Problem was in javascript code with model definitions. I had 3 separate viewmodels:
student,
grade,
subject.
I tried to add 2 lists into one table, from two diffrent viemodels.
The problem is that you can bind only one viewmodel to a table, not more- thats why i couldnt get a list of students, when table was already bound to grades.
So i decided to put everything in one model (student,grades,subjects), and now its working perfectly.
I dont think that any code is neeed, its just 'idea trick'.